# jquery- does selecting by var works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When i typed the following code:

```
var var1=document.createElement("div");
$(var1).click(function()....);
```

This type of selector worked for me, but i didn't found any reference about it.
does it work for every browser?

Comment: it should work what i think

Comment: Of course; why wouldn't it work? You're creating an element and assigning a function to its click event

Comment: but you have to use delegated event

Comment: `var1` is not a selector it's the dom element itself the click event will only attach that particular div and not other divs.

Comment: the reference is right here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element (in the ***Core*** section).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using a selector.  There are multiple overloads of the `jQuery()` method to create a jquery object.  It can take, for example, a selector, an HTML string, or, and this is what you're doing, [a reference to an actual DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element).